# Google Event Tracking on Mobile Website

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Tested on Android Marshmallow Chrome and iOS 7 Safari

Google Analytics event tracking fails to fire after clearing all website data.

When I refresh the page it works perfectly.

I've tried putting GA Async to false but that doesn't help either.

Nothing found when searching on Google or Stack Overflow, hence posting the question. Hope someone can help.

Code only works after refresh:

```
/* Google Tracking */
 //Universal GA tracking included as usual and then...
 ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'mywebsite.co.uk');
 ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
 ga('send', 'pageview');
 ga('send', 'event','test', 'test2', 'test3', '1'); //Not working on    iPhone & Marshmallow Android
 /* End Google Tracking *
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you using the Android and iOS SDKs? Is this for a mobile app, because the code looks like it's only for a web app.

Comment: It's just a website, not an app

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. Would you mind clarifying your post, as it mentions Android and iOS, which could lead one to think it's related to mobile apps. But I guess you could also imply that you were testing these on a web browser on those platforms??

Comment: OK done I've added the term website and put browsers in

Comment: Have you tried checking from a desktop browser to see if you if the event tracking works? You could use GA Debugger, or analyse your Network console.

Comment: Hi there. Yes desktop works fine, it's only on mobile it doesn't work.